# Do older versions of cards use the card types printed on the newest version?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

On the older versions of the Magic: The Gathering card [Lord of Atlantis](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lord%20of%20Atlantis) the card type was listed as "Summon Lord" but on the newer versions it is listed as "Merfolk Lord".

If I play the old version of the card does it use the new card type or the old card type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is a Merfolk regardless of what version you use. (Lord is an obsolete creature type.) To find the official text and characteristics of a card, you should use [Gatherer](http://Gatherer.Wizards.com).

> **205.3f** Many cards were printed with subtypes that are now obsolete. Many cards have retroactively received subtypes. Use the Oracle card reference to determine what a card’s subtypes are.
>
> **108.1.** Use the Oracle™ card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at Gatherer.Wizards.com.